# Can external usb graphic card replace basic integrated graphic?

Tags: graphics-card, external-display, integrated-graphics

Hello I have some old server computer which have integrated graphic card and it use old slot, that server I want to use for some working but the resolution is too low, so what i want is to  connect usb external graphic drive which have better resolution and use those graphic when working, my goal is to have better quality resolution. So now my question is:

**If i connect usb external graphic card on old server computer with low resolution graphic would i get better resoulution?**

External graphic card is Arkview USB-DH88 Multi-Display USB 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could get a higher resolution. But performance would be quite low due to USB2 bandwidth limits. If you only want to do some basic management tasks then it will suffice.

However consider an alternative solution: RDP.

You can remote desktop into the server from another computer and set the resolution of the RDP session to whatever you desire.

Comment: thnx for answare let's say that i want to programming or writing some text i expect that will work normal and if i let's say try to record some tasks like recording screen in Camtasia that will be little slower?

Comment: Recording a screen is likely to consume a lot of bandwidth. (Which depends on resolution used, colour depth etc). That might get tricky. -- Some text would be fine.